# Getting tabs in vim instead of spaces even with `set expandtab`

Tags: vim, tabs, vi, space

I create the file "tabtest" by `vi tabtest` and then typing:

```
a
tab
b
newline  
c
tab
d  
CTRL-C
:
wq
```

I have `set expandtab` in my `.vimrc. But I'm *still* getting tabs in the file instead of spaces.

```
(base) balter@ab-rstudio:~$ cat -A tabtest
a^Ib$
^Ic^Id$
```

```
(base) balter@ab-rstudio:~$ cat .vimrc
let python_highlight_all = 1

set undodir=${HOME}/.vim/undo/
set backupdir=${HOME}/.vim/backup/
set directory=~/.vim/swp/
set writebackup
set noswapfile

set autoindent
set showmatch
set mouse=a
syntax on

set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=0
set shiftwidth=4
set textwidth=79
set expandtab
set smarttab
set autoindent
set fileformat=unix

set backspace=indent,eol,start
set whichwrap+=<,>,h,l,[,]

set laststatus=2
set statusline+=%F

colorscheme murphy

set paste
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the golden rules of tool customization is to only put stuff you understand in your config. The first step toward that understanding is to *read* (not skim) the documentation for any option or command you plan to add and then, armed with that newfound knowledge, *ponder* the pros and cons of doing so.

`:help 'paste'` is a very powerful option with *many* explicitly documented side effects, such as:

```
When the 'paste' option is switched on (also when it was already on):
        [...]
        - 'expandtab' is reset
        [...]
```

That option should never be set in one's `vimrc` because of all those nasty side effects that are desirable *only when using the terminal/system's pasting facilities* but very undesirable *the rest of the time*. Remove it.

Here is how it generally goes:

1. user tries to paste something with the terminal's "paste" thing and gets garbled text,
2. user looks it up on the internet, learns about the `paste` option, and never bothers to read its documentation,
3. user quickly gets tired of that `:set paste<CR><whatever>:set nopaste<CR>` dance and decides to add `set paste` to their `vimrc` so that it is always on,
4. user notices issues with indenting or insert mode mappings but is unable to relate them to their nifty idea of adding `set paste` to their `vimrc`… because they have no idea of what the option actually does,
5. user turns *once again* to the internet, which reminds them that reading the doc in due time would have made them aware of the pitfalls of `set paste` *and* led them to `:help 'pastetoggle'`, which solves the repetitiveness issue nicely without adding `set paste` to their `vimrc`,
6. user is, hopefully, enlightened.

But, of course, the real solution is to get a proper Vim with clipboard support, but that's another, beaten to death, story.